# How to filter out items in jquery that don't belong in search results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have this setup below where if I search a term under Day 2, that isn't contained in Day 1, then the Day 1 header will still display. If no search results are present under a particular header, how do I **NOT** display that header?

In other words, search Daredevil, which is only under Day 2 and the Day 1 header should not display at all.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".container .card").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row py-2">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="search" id="myInput" placeholder="Start typing.." name="search" class="form-control searchbox-input" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row no-gutters bg-info">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 p-3">
          <h2>Day 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 p-3">
          <h2>April 7, 2019</h2>
        </div>
      </div>      
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Batman</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Superman</h4>
      <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
        <footer>
          <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="row no-gutters bg-warning">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 p-3">
          <h2>Day 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 p-3">
          <h2>April 8, 2019</h2>
        </div>
      </div>       
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Daredevil</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-body card-inverse card-primary text-xs-center">
      <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
        <footer>
          <small>
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-body text-xs-center">
      <h4 class="card-title">Hulk</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-body text-xs-right">
      <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
        <footer>
          <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Thor</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to toggle inside the `.filter` even no need to toggle.. you can use `.show()` and `.hide()` **OR** `.slideDown()` and `.slideUp()` **OR** `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` .. see the example below and read a comments in the code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".container .card").hide().closest('.row').hide(); // hide all cards and its closest rows
    $(".container .card").filter(function() {
      return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1; // return true or false from filter
    }).show().closest('.row').show(); // then show the card and its closest row after filter
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row py-2">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="search" id="myInput" placeholder="Start typing.." name="search" class="form-control searchbox-input" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row no-gutters bg-info">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 p-3">
          <h2>Day 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 p-3">
          <h2>April 7, 2019</h2>
        </div>
      </div>      
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Batman</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Superman</h4>
      <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
        <footer>
          <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="row no-gutters bg-warning">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 p-3">
          <h2>Day 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 p-3">
          <h2>April 8, 2019</h2>
        </div>
      </div>       
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Daredevil</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-body card-inverse card-primary text-xs-center">
      <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
        <footer>
          <small>
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-body text-xs-center">
      <h4 class="card-title">Hulk</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-body text-xs-right">
      <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
        <footer>
          <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Thor</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```